# Write MDS business rules directly in SQL

Tags: sql, master-data-services, mds

I'm using Master Data Services to check business rules in SQL. The use of MDS makes it easy for any (non-coder) to add business rules. However, I initially need to add a large amount of business rules and this is a very tedious procedure in MDS.

Is there a way to write the MDS business rules directly in code and add them to the MDS database?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a couple of stored procedures used for updating the MDS, but is is quite difficult to figure out how to use them. (And you can mess up the model if used incorrectly)

Easier would be to try the Business Rules Create method.

This is where you can get started with webservices:
http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mds_team/archive/2010/01/12/getting-started-with-the-web-services-api-in-sql-server-2008-r2-master-data-services.aspx

This is where the method is defined:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.masterdataservices.services.servicecontracts.iservice.businessrulescreate(v=sql.120).aspx

You will need to weigh your options whether it would be faster to figure out how to do one of the above, or just knuckle down and create the business rules. MDS 2016 is much more user friendly than the previous versions when creating business rules(fyi)